# How do I define all inputs in rails to be read in one timezone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need some help with Timezones. I want all of my inputs for Clock.new to CREATE/POST as PST rather than UTC, but I'm not have any success with my attempts. I have two database fields one for time_start, and time_end.

In my application.rb file I have tried setting a local timezone, based on what I found in other SO questions, but that doesn't seem to be working for me.

```
module Timer
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
    config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Iin your application.rb

```
#application.rb
config.time_zone = 'London' 
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

Here set the value_of time_zone based on your country. 
in your rails console run below command to get list of available timezones.

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.map(&:name)

Dont forget to restart your server after above changes!
```

Comment: Thanks! rake time:zones:local gives a list of all available time-zones.